# How to insert variable into formatted text in ruby

Tags: ruby

So I have a string formatted with triple quotation marks or %q{} like this and I want to insert a variable into the string; apparently using #{variable} wouldn't work.

```
variable = "some string" 
puts %q{
My string looks like
this and i want to show
my string here #{variable}
}
```

Comment: Use a big Q and it works! http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use uppercase "Q"

```
variable = "some string"
%Q{ My math #{1+1} and string #{variable}}
```